# Is there any Android Update Service which can let me know about OS or any new update via JSON or Email?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, android-notifications

I want to get an email from android or ios which can let me know about the latest update they released. I found it on [https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAaRn.png) but I can not get it programmatically.I tried it with the URL https://www.android.com/versions/ but it didn't worked please tell me if there is any method to get the latest version information even in JSON. Same is applicable for ios also. Thanks in advance.
[image: here I can see that the latest version released is nougat. I need it as notification]

Comment: parsing http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html this page can get me the detail but I don't think it will be stable.